# database_sync_to_async not working in django channels consumers

Tags: django, asynchronous, websocket, channel

[This is my consumers file and I am using AsyncWebSocketConsumer. And Get details function is not working.](https://i.stack.i)

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
    self.room_group_name = 'notification_%s' % self.room_name
    notificationobjs=await self.get_details(self.room_name)
    # unseencount=application_notifications.objects.filter(User=User.objects.get(username=self.room_name),is_seen=False).count()
    data={'notifications':NotificationSerializer(notificationobjs,many=True).data,'count':0}

    print(self.room_group_name)
    
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status':'connected','user':self.room_group_name,'payload':data}))

@database_sync_to_async
def get_details(self,room_name):
    return application_notifications.objects.filter(User=User.objects.get(username=room_name))
```

Its Showing the error "django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async."

If Anyone can help me solve this issue, It would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.